# Is `isNaN`' a bad design or a has-to-be design with tradeoffs?

Tags: design, javascript, programming-languages, language-design

My first programming language is python. And recently I'm learning C and javascript.
In javascript, there is a design which confused me a lot, default the function `isNaN`.

Put aside its weird exceptions in specification(Which is hard to find), such as `isNaN("")`, `isNaN(["22"])`.
The more frustrating thing is that the result of `isNaN` consumes my thinking energy, though a tiny bit every time, before I established an intuition about it.(Which requires quite a bit of efforts)

But man, we are lazy. And this design does not follow the human instinct.
The examples below records how my brain works when seeing the two types of expressions in python and javascript:

```
isNaN(n)
false

# THOUGHTS:
# The result of isNaN(n) is false, what does it mean?
# it means n is not a number is false.
# OK, let me think for a while..
# So, I assume it is a number(with hesitation)


type(n) == int
False

# THOUGHTS:
# type(n) == int returns False, what does it mean?
# So it tells us that `the type of n equals int` is false
# So the type of n is not equal to int!
# I think n is not a int.
```

I think human beings have a tendency to assume everything is True at first.
Thus multiple negative levels on statement will increase our recognition cost.
On this sight of view, the design of `isNaN` is a bad one, and `isN`(isNumber) is a better solution for human understanding.
But as a sceptic, I'm wondering there may have some background story about this design, to achieving a important functionality, the author chosen this design as a tradeoff?
Was there a good reason, or is this just a design deficiency(in the sense of human friendly)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of NaN boxing?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/185406/what-is-the-purpose-of-nan-boxing)

Comment: Notwithstanding the long history of IEEE floating point, Javascript and computing in general, the intuition that you are asking about has been [answered in an earlier question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/245375/naming-boolean-variables-negated-or-not).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The purpose of `isNaN` is not to check if a value is nummeric or not. It actual purpose is to check if a floating point number has the special value of `NaN`. The special `NaN` value is assigned to the results of mathematically impossible operations, like dividing 0/0 or converting an alphabetic string to a number.

However, when you try to use isNaN on a value which is not a floating-point number, Javascript first tries to convert it to a number and then checks if that number has the special `NaN` value. To make matters more confusing, `undefined` is also treated as `NaN` by Javascript, so when the value can not be converted to a number, it is considered `NaN`.

To protect yourself from headache, only use `isNaN` when you are really looking for the floating point `NaN` value.

When you want to know if a variable is a number, use `typeof variable == 'number'` (the value of `NaN` is also of type number, by the way). When you want to know if a string can be converted to a number, use `isNaN(Number(variable))`.

Comment: only use isNaN when you know the argument is a number, more like. Excluding the special case later.

Comment: Good answer, but it contains one imprecision: There is not just one special NaN, but a whole plethora of different values that are treated as NaNs. Especially there is a distinction between signaling and quiet NaNs. However, these are hardware specifics, all languages treat all NaNs exactly the same, so your answer is close enough; I would just recommend to speak of NaNs as plural not as "the special `NaN` value".

Answer (score 11):

["Not a Number" (NaN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) has its roots in something much larger than JavaScript.  You have to go back to 1985 and the [IEEE-754 standard](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/) for floating point mathematics to understand it.  NaNs occur in several ways during mathematical operations (*e.g.*, division of 0 by 0), and `isNaN()` functions are intended to determine when a putative number is in fact not a number.  JavaScript's particular implementation of `isNaN()` is, unfortunately, a byproduct of its willingness to treat values that aren't obviously numbers as numbers.

Comment: Nitpick: Division by 0 generally results in +/- infinity. Operations that produce NaN include 0/0 and `sqrt(negativeNumber)`.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript's `isNaN` is a bit of a botched job on the concept of what Not-A-Number represents. The intent of `NaN` is to represent indeterminate numerical forms such as 0/0 or ∞/∞, and to represent the result of out-of-range numerical calculations such as `sqrt(-1)` and `asin(2)`. The ES6 release of ECMAScript addresses this issue by adding the `Number.isNaN` function. This new function doesn't coerce a non-numeric value into a numeric value before testing. The result of calling `Number.isNaN` with a non-numeric value is false. This makes it clearer that the purpose of `isNaN` is to test for a numerical value that does not represent a numerical value.

There's a funny thing about NaNs: Arithmetic comparisons that involves a NaN must always return false. Even `x == x` (or `x===x` in javascript) will return false in the special case that `x` is a NaN. Anything but a NaN will compare equal to itself, yielding a cryptic way of testing whether something is a NaN. Using `isNaN(x)` does a much better job of conveying intent than does `!(x==x)`.